# Textarea не принимает нужную высоту при загрузке страницы

Tags: forms, textarea

Здравствуйте!
Не получается сделать так, чтобы текстареа принимала высоту содержимого сразу после зугрузки страницы, а не при нажатии на саму текстареа :-(

Код ниже

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
<head>
<title>xiper.net - пример textarea подстраивается под высоту текста</title>

<link href="http://www.xiper.net/examples/css/examples.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.4.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/autoresize.jquery.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function()
    {
        jQuery('textarea').autoResize({
            // On resize:
            onResize : function() {
                jQuery(this).css({color:'#fff', backgroundColor:'#fff'});
            },
            // After resize:
            animateCallback : function() {
                jQuery(this).css({color:'#000', backgroundColor:'#fff'});
            }
        });

    });
</script>
<style type="text/css">
<!--
form{
    margin:10px;
}
form div{
    margin-bottom:10px;
}
textarea{
    padding:10px;
    width:400px;
    border:1px solid #999;
    overflow:hidden;
    display:block;

}
-->
</style>
</head>
<body>

    <form action="#" method="post">
        <div>
            <textarea>
AutoResize – a jQuery plugin (1kb minified) which enables animated auto-resizing of textarea form elements.

When a user inputs text into a textarea the plugin automatically keeps track of their progress and will expand the textarea when needed.

The plugin has been tested successfully in IE6/7, FF2/3, Opera9, Safari3 & Chrome.

</textarea>

    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Скрипт работает так как его сделали программисты. У меня не получается его переделать так, чтобы textarea принимала нужную высоту сразу при загрузке, а не при нажатии на неё )

Comment: скрипт работает как он настроен, найти там цсс свойства и выстави нужные размеры, посмотри в фейрбеге кто кого перекрывает и подправь

Answer (score 1):

1. Проверьте консоль на наличие ошибок
2. Проверьте или все файлы загружаются (`js/jquery-1.4.2.js, js/autoresize.jquery.js`). Они у вас точно есть в папке js?

Comment: Не-не-не :)
Всё не то.

Надо внести поправку в код ниже, чтобы он срабатывал сразу после загрузки страницы. 

<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function()
    {
        jQuery('textarea').autoResize({
            // On resize:
            onResize : function() {
                jQuery(this).css({color:'#fff', backgroundColor:'#fff'});
            },
            // After resize:
            animateCallback : function() {
                jQuery(this).css({color:'#000', backgroundColor:'#fff'});
            }
        });

    });